# sql confusion with ANDs

Tags: sql

I am having a bit of confusion with SQL querying using ANDs.

the query is as follows:

```
SELECT  count(cdr.id) as callTotal,
    sum(cdr.callDurationSeconds) as timeTotal,
    users.firstname,
    users.surname, 
    MAX(cdr.callDuration) as maxCallDuration,
    AVG(cdr.answeredTime) as avgAnswerTime,
    AVG(cdr.callDurationSeconds) as avgTimeTotal,
    cdr.userId, 
    COUNT(IF(cdr.callDurationSeconds > '0', 1, NULL)) AS answeredCalls
                 FROM cdr 
                 LEFT JOIN users ON cdr.userId = users.id
                 WHERE cdr.company = 'C47B0BCCDCE92F'
                 AND cdr.dateCreated LIKE '2012-11-02%'  
                 AND  cdr.userId = 'U4BC3128209B01'  
   OR  cdr.userId = 'U4A9FCCD73C6BB'  
   GROUP BY userId  ORDER BY users.surname ASC  ;
```

I want to query by the date on the second to last line, but then I wish to retrieve items with any of the posted cdr.userIds.
However it seems to disregard the date in this instance. I need the date to be non-optional and retrieve any data with the select Ids on the chosen date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL AND has a higher order then OR so by default your where resolves to

```
             WHERE (cdr.company = 'C47B0BCCDCE92F'
             AND cdr.dateCreated LIKE '2012-11-02%'  
             AND  cdr.userId = 'U4BC3128209B01')  OR  cdr.userId = 'U4A9FCCD73C6BB'
```

Where you want

```
             WHERE cdr.company = 'C47B0BCCDCE92F'
             AND cdr.dateCreated LIKE '2012-11-02%'  
             AND  (cdr.userId = 'U4BC3128209B01'  OR  cdr.userId = 'U4A9FCCD73C6BB')
```

Use brackets and it will clear things up.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't wanna play with `OR` / `AND` operators precedence in SQL (which is a rather bad idea), just add brackets.

```
AND  (cdr.userId = 'U4BC3128209B01'  OR  cdr.userId = 'U4A9FCCD73C6BB')
```

or as pointed by Martin Smith, in your case, use an `IN`

```
AND cdr.userId IN  ('U4BC3128209B01','U4A9FCCD73C6BB')
```

Comment: or could use `AND cdr.userId IN ('U4BC3128209B01','U4A9FCCD73C6BB')`

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the `OR` with parenthesis like the others mentioned or use IN like this

```
SELECT  count(cdr.id) as callTotal,
                         sum(cdr.callDurationSeconds) as timeTotal,
                         users.firstname,
                         users.surname, 
                         MAX(cdr.callDuration) as maxCallDuration,
                         AVG(cdr.answeredTime) as avgAnswerTime,
                         AVG(cdr.callDurationSeconds) as avgTimeTotal,
                         cdr.userId, 
                         COUNT(IF(cdr.callDurationSeconds > '0', 1, NULL)) AS answeredCalls
                 FROM cdr 
                 LEFT JOIN users ON cdr.userId = users.id
                 WHERE cdr.company = 'C47B0BCCDCE92F'
                 AND cdr.dateCreated LIKE '2012-11-02%'  
                 AND  cdr.userId IN ('U4BC3128209B01','U4A9FCCD73C6BB')  GROUP BY userId  ORDER BY users.surname ASC  ;
```

That way there's no `OR`, so no confusion

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to select the items with that date AND have a specific id?

```
SELECT  count(cdr.id) as callTotal,
                         sum(cdr.callDurationSeconds) as timeTotal,
                         users.firstname,
                         users.surname, 
                         MAX(cdr.callDuration) as maxCallDuration,
                         AVG(cdr.answeredTime) as avgAnswerTime,
                         AVG(cdr.callDurationSeconds) as avgTimeTotal,
                         cdr.userId, 
                         COUNT(IF(cdr.callDurationSeconds > '0', 1, NULL)) AS answeredCalls
                 FROM cdr 
                 LEFT JOIN users ON cdr.userId = users.id
                 WHERE cdr.company = 'C47B0BCCDCE92F'
                 AND cdr.dateCreated LIKE '2012-11-02%'  
                     AND  cdr.userId IN('U4BC3128209B01','U4A9FCCD73C6BB')
                 GROUP BY userId  ORDER BY users.surname ASC  ;
```